# jQuery - Add html code inside a DIV block

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to add html code inside a div block?
here's my html code

```
<div id="content-area">
<p>welcome to ...</p>
</div>
```

I would like to insert new block after  `<div id="content-area">`
with the ff code `<p class='info'>Information...</p>`

so it will output like.

```
<div id="content-area">
<p class='info'>Information...</p>
    <p>welcome to ...</p>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: sorry, still new to jquery. My search didn't take me to that page.

Comment: If you wonder how to do something in jQuery, the official documentation is the first place you should look (http://api.jquery.com/). Or the tutorials: http://learn.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#content-area').prepend("<p class='info'>Information...</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.prepend`

```
$('#content-area').prepend($('<p>', { 'className' : 'info',text : 'your text'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = $('<p />', {'class':'info', text: 'Information...'});

$('.content-area').prepend(p);
```